# Create a linked vector and lists

Tags: c++, list, vector, stl

I want to create vector which stores pointers to lists as shown in image.[image: This is how it looks]
 I don't know how many lists will be needed here. So, I want to write function like this

```
vector<node*> address; //node is class.
if ((int)address.size()<number)  //number is integer taken as input to function.
    { while((int)address.size()!=number)
        {address.push(/*here I want some function which will generate
 empty list and return pointer to head node or any information 
that will help to access list later*/)
        }
else
{    address[number-1].push_back(name); //name has type string;
//this line may be wrong for syntax but idea is A[i] gives me 
   // list where I want to put name.

}
```

Preferably using STL library.

Comment: Using just the C++ (2011) standard library: `std::vector<std::list<std::shared_ptr<node>>> addresses;`

Comment: This is called a *jagged array*, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use STL library, then just use

```
std::vector<std::list<node>> address; //node is class (note that you can pass size here)

// Using your code in your code:
if ((int)address.size() < number)  //number is integer taken as input to function.
{
        address.resize(number);
}
else
{    address.back().push_back(name); //name has type string;

}
```

Please note that the `node` is type of the elements you want to push into the vector. As @john said, if you want to keep a list of strings then declare `address` as:

```
 std::vector<std::list<std::string>> address;
```

Also, if you get errors because of `>>`, either compile this as C++11, or write `address` as:

```
 std::vector<std::list<std::string> > address;
```

Comment: Presumably since Nikhil is adding strings to the linked list, it would actually be `std::vector<std::list<std::string>> collection`;

Comment: Will collection(number).push_back(name) work? [for inserting names in corresp. list]

Comment: @Nikhil, it would if you declare your type as in my comment.

Comment: and for while loop I will write: A.push(std::list<string> temp)//this will add empty list in vector right?[declaring temp as list of string type]

Comment: @Nikhil Yes, it will add emtpy lists to the vector. And you can just use `back()` method on vector to get the last element.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric There's a typo in your code, missing parens and semi `address.push(std::list<node>());`

Comment: @john However, I went with `resize()`.

Comment: @Nikhil `collection[0].push_back(p);`

Comment: @Nikhil Use `operator[]` and not `operator()`

Answer (score 1):

It is not much clear, but I guess you want an automatic resize container (as javascript vectors) where lists indexes are 1 based (i.e. no list at address 0) and a method to insert at the end of one list at a given index. Basically something as this:

```
struct MyCollection: public std::vector<std::list<std::string> > {
    void push_at(size_t index, const std::string& item) {
        resize(std::max(size(),index - 1);
        at(index - 1).push_back(item);
    }
};
```

Anything else you might want from such container is likely to be already implemented in the `vector` and `list` template classes (check stl documentation to see whats available), for example:

```
MyCollection a; //declares an empty collection
a.push_at(6,"hello"); //create 6 lists and inserts "hello" at the end of the last one
a[5]; //gets 6th list (method [] is 0-based on vector)
a.push_at(6,"hi"); // since list already exists it just adds "hi" at the end
a[5].front() //"hello"
a[5].back() //"hi"
```

Other suggestions:

- if you plan to put a lot of items in there and do not need to have all lists object at consecutive addresses (i.e. compatibility of vector with C arrays), I suggest you use a `deque` instead of a `vector`, or provide a proper size hint with `reserve`, otherwise you might be find yourself wondering why sometimes adding a single string in a list that does not exists yet is so slow.
- STL uses 0-based indexes all around. You will only get confused by defining a 1-based one, so count your lists from 0 (just replace `index - 1` with `index` in the example above) and do your math on application logic)